# Why doesn't this jQuery function work on Android 2.3?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, function

I have a function that's supposed to adjust some elements within navigation for mobile devices, but it doesn't work on Android 2.3, can you please tell me what's wrong with it?

```
function mobileNavTop () {
  if($(document).scrollTop() <= 25) {
    $('#mobile-navigation').css({'position':'absolute', 'right':'0', 'top':'18px'});
    $('.jq1').css({'position':'absolute'});
    $('.move_up').hide();
  } else {
    $('#mobile-navigation').removeAttr('style');
    $('.jq1').removeAttr('style');
    $('.move_up').removeAttr('style');
  }
}
```

Also I see that Android browser doesn't support `scrollTop()` property, how could I replace that?